# How to make transformation of value for binding or state

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to understand how to transform value from model to view. For example, I have a model:

```
struct BloodPressure {  
    var systolic: Int = 0
    var diastolic: Int = 0
}
```

And I have a view:

```
struct MeasurementsTabView: View {
    @State private var bloodPressure = BloodPressure()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Systolic", text: $bloodPressure.systolic)
            TextField("Diastolic", text: $bloodPressure.diastolic)
        }
    }
}
```

There is an error, because `text` parameter should be a string, but `bloodPressure.systolic` is `Int`.

I found a solution, but I think that isn't elegant:

```
var body: some View {
    let systolicBinding = Binding <String> (
        get: { String(self.bloodPressure.systolic) },
        set: {
            if let int = Int($0) {
                self.bloodPressure.systolic = int
            }
        })

    let diastolicBinding = Binding <String> (
        get: { String(self.bloodPressure.diastolic) },
        set: {
            if let int = Int($0) {
                self.bloodPressure.diastolic = int
            }
        })

    return VStack {
        TextField("Systolic", text: systolicBinding)
        TextField("Diastolic", text: diastolicBinding)
    }
}
```

How you solve similar issues?

Answer (score 2):

In this case I recommend to introduce ViewModel layer, so BloodPressure remains pure model.

Below is simplified demo of concept (eg. formatting/validation of text fields is out of scope, etc.)

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct BloodPressure {
    var systolic: Int = 0
    var diastolic: Int = 0
}

class BloodPressureViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var model: BloodPressure

    init(_ model: BloodPressure) {
        self.systolic = String(model.systolic)
        self.diastolic = String(model.diastolic)

        self.model = model
    }
    @Published var systolic: String = "" {
        didSet {
            self.model.systolic = Int(self.systolic) ?? 0
        }
    }
    @Published var diastolic: String = "" {
        didSet {
            self.model.diastolic = Int(self.diastolic) ?? 0
        }
    }
}


struct MeasurementsTabView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: BloodPressureViewModel

    init(bloodPressure: BloodPressure) {
        viewModel = BloodPressureViewModel(bloodPressure)
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Systolic", text: $viewModel.systolic)
            TextField("Diastolic", text: $viewModel.diastolic)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but It looks a little complex for easy bindings

Comment: `Published` is unuseful in your case